# iMacros : check random Radio button/Checkbox

Tags: macros, automation, imacros, browser-automation

I would like to check only one radio button (or checkbox), they are differents by the POS

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ACTION:http://www.signup.com/index.php ATTR=NAME:my_input_radio CONTENT=YES
```

With POS randomly sets between 1 and 8

I would like to make it like that :

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var r=Math.floor(Math.random()*8+1);r;")
TAG POS={{!VAR1}} TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ACTION:http://www.signup.com/index.php ATTR=NAME:my_input_radio CONTENT=YES
```

But when I run the iMacros script, it searches for POS {{!VAR1}} and not POS 4 (for example, according that the precedent SET returned 4 to VAR1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is just one then you can try this code and set the loop from 1 to 8.

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ACTION:http://www.signup.com/index.php ATTR=NAME:my_input_radio CONTENT=YES
```

Comment: That will not work for my script. I have multiple form to complete. !LOOP is designed to, when a macro is launched in X times loop, increment itself from 1 to X each time the macro is re-launched. I need the value to be random each time and at each form. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Then you can use javascript scripting. and iimSet command to set the random number into the iMacros code.